# Is it better to define a trait function taking a reference to self or take self directly and implement the trait on a reference to the type?

Tags: rust

Is it better to define a trait with a function taking a (mutable or not) reference to self and implementing the trait on the structure directly like this:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

struct A {}

impl Foo for A {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("A::foo");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    a.foo();
}
```

Or define a trait with a function taking self directly and implementing the trait on the (mutable or not) reference of the structure like this:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(self);
}

struct A {}
impl Foo for &A {
    fn foo(self) {
        println!("A::foo");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    a.foo();
}
```

I've seen this kind of implementation in the standard library: `IntoIterator`  is implemented for `&mut Vec<T>`.

I find the second way more interesting because we can write the trait without assuming how the instance must be considered regarding the described behaviour, but I wonder if there's a consensus or a guideline on this that I might not have seen.

Why does the `Fn` trait also require the `FnOnce` and `FnMut` traits regarding this implementation? I know that this implementation is experimental, but still, most of the time, `FnOnce` is the most used for constraints. Why we don't have something like this instead:

```
trait Fn<Args> {
    type Output;
    fn call(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}

impl Fn<i32> for Foo { ... } // instead of FnOnce
impl Fn<i32> for &Bar { ... } // instead of current Fn trait
impl Fn<i32> for &mut Baz { ... } //instead of FnMut
```

Comment: Overall, there are so many aspects of this question – style, API design, Rust-specific idiosyncracies – that I find it hard to answer in its current very general form.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It seems it [does not consume the mutable reference, or maybe I missed something](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8442645550fdd7b23906999ca2f4542c)

Comment: Duh. I tested this with a `for` loop as a proxy for `.into_iter()`, but it turns out that the `for` loop consumes the mutable reference, while `into_iter()` doesn't. I thought I had an understanding of that part of Rust semantics, but it turns out I was wrong.